# My display none to flex transition won't fade, even though it's a separate fade animation

Tags: html, css

```css
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from { opacity: 0; }
      to { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
    from { opacity: 0; }
      to { opacity: 1; }
}





html {
    background-color: rgb(26, 30, 32);
}
* {
    color: white;
}
body {
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgb(26, 30, 32);
}
.wrapper {
    visibility: visible;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
}



.page:target {
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.5s;
    animation: fadeIn 0.5s;
}
.page:not(:target) {
    display: none;
}
.page {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.page .section {
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

h2 {
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: capitalize ;
}




.button-fill {
    width: fit-content;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.button-fill:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: rgb(26, 30, 32);
    cursor: pointer;
}



.button-unfill {
    width: fit-content;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(175, 175, 175);
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: rgb(175, 175, 175);
    background-color: transparent;
    transition: 0.4s ease;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: small;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.button-unfill:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    cursor: pointer;
}





.popup {
    background-color: rgb(42, 48, 51);
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    display: flex;
    width: 75%;
    height: max-content;
    margin: 50px auto auto auto;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 2.5px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 1px #00000070;
}
.popup .options {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 50px;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.popup .close {
    font-size: xx-large;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: -8px;
}
.popup .back {
    font-size: xx-large;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: -8px;
}
.popup:not(:target) {
    display: none;
}
.popup:target {
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 0.5s;
    animation: fadeIn 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Royeghem</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav">

    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="#home">
            <button class="button-unfill">
                Home
            </button>
        </a>
        <a href="#elements">
            <button class="button-unfill">
                Elements
            </button>
        </a>
        <div class="page" id="elements">

            <div class="section" id="section-buttons">
                <h2>Buttons</h2>
                <button class="button-fill">
                    Button
                </button>
        
                <button class="button-unfill">
                    Button
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="section" id="section-popups">
                <h2>Popups</h2>
                <a href="#popup">
                    <button class="button-unfill">
                        Popup
                    </button>
                </a>
            </div>
    
        </div>









        
        <div class="page" id="home">
            <div class="section" id="section-buttons">
                <h2>Buttons</h2>
                <button class="button-fill">
                    Button
                </button>
        
                <button class="button-unfill">
                    Button
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="section" id="section-popups">
                <h2>Popups</h2>
                <a href="#popup">
                    <button class="button-unfill">
                        Popup
                    </button>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        
        <div id="popup" xml:id="popup2" class="popup">
            <div class="options">
                <a href="#elements" class="close">&times;</a>
                <a href="#elements" class="back">&#8701;</a>
            </div>
            <h2>A Popup</h2>
            <p>This is a random popup, but it can also be used as a seperate page.</p>
            <p>A popup inside a popup is also possible!</p>
            <a href="#popup2">
                <button class="button-unfill">
                    Popup 2
                </button>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div id="popup2" class="popup">
            <div class="options">
                <a href="#elements" class="close">&times;</a>
                <a href="#popup" class="back">&#8701;</a>
            </div>
            <h2>A Popup</h2>
            <p>This is a second popup inside another one. Here the back arrow goes to the previous popup and the cross goes back to the elements page.</p>
        </div>

    </div>

        
        
</body>
</html>
```

This is my code. It works fine, but then if you try to navigate through the pages and popups, some stop fading in. I have been searching for a good reason, but couldn't think of anything, so I'm giving some experts the chance to explain this to me.

Any reason why it stops fading in and/or how I can fix it?
Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: You cannot animate/transition the `display` property

Comment: I know. That's why I didn't go for transition and instead went for a separate animation, with keyframes.

Comment: Because, why shouldn't that work?